# degenerate plane in $\mathbb{C}^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology

Does someone know about "degenerate plane"?when do we say a plane in $\mathbb{C}^3$ namely $a z_1 + bz_2 + c z_3 = d$ where $a,b,c,d$ are complex constants ,  to be degenerate? Is there any reference for this?

Answer (score 0):

Where did you encounter the term?
I would understand this as $\mathbb{C}^3$ i.e. the case when equation is tautological.

Comment: what do you mean by tautological?

Comment: $0=0$, also, in your case i think it is just $a=b=c=0$ and $d$ is arbitrary